# Elastic Beanstalk Blue Green Deployment Without Approval Step

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, blue-green-deployment

My team and I are looking into added no-downtime deployments to our front ends which currently live on Elastic Beanstalk.  We currently have a CI pipeline using AWS CodePipeline and we want to modify it so that it can use blue green deployments.

I've been doing a lot of reading on the topic,  and followed the guide found here:

https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-codepipeline-bluegreen-deployment/doc/blue-green-deployments-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf

[image]

My question is regarding removing the approval step,  which our team doesn't feel is necessary for our use case.

If we remove the manual approval?  how will the pipeline know to continue?  I understand you can send a message when the Elastic Beanstalk Environment has been updated, but I don't see a way in which that message could notifiy the pipeline to advance a step.

Has anyone run into this challenge before? Or have any suggestions about blue green implementations on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the manual approval stops the pipeline from continuing to the next action, so removing it means the pipeline will advance to the next action without intervention.

You'll probably want to make sure you have a reasonable level of automated testing and automate anything you currently do before approving the manual approval.